# How to detect a Python type implements buffer protocol or not?

Tags: python, c++

Looking at the Python C API, it is clear that you need to set the tp_as_buffer field in order to implement the buffer protocol:

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_as_buffer

However, it seems that this field is not initialized for a type object. This field tp_as_buffer may or may not be NULL. So I can't count on a predicate like "tObj->tp_as_buffer==nullptr" to figure out the type is a buffer protocol or not. Any ideas how to check whether a Python type implements buffer protocol?

Comment: Isn't this what `PyObject_CheckBuffer` is for, or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: In the case when an instance object is obtained, PyObject_CheckBuffer would work. In my case, what I get is a type object.